# Data not displaying in django admin - using chart.js (no errors)

Tags: django, django-admin, chart.js, python-3.7

I have created a changelist_view for displaying a chart.js visual in the Django admin.
I am not getting any errors, the chart outline is visible, but the data is not. Not sure what I'm missing. Info below:

admin.py model:

```
class MachineFaultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
readonly_fields = [
    'event_id',
    'fault_type_id',
    'position',
]
list_display = [
    'event_id',
    'fault_type_id',
    'position',
]

def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    # Aggregate Faults
    chart_data = (
        MachineFault.objects.all()
        .values('position')
        .annotate(total=Count('fault_type_id'))
        .order_by('total')
        .filter(position__gte=10)
    )

    #Serialize and attach the chart data to the template context
    as_json = json.dumps(list(chart_data), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    extra_context = extra_context or {"chart_data": as_json}

    #Call the superclass changelist_view to render the page
    return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)

def has_add_permission(self, request):
    # Nobody is allowed to add
    return False

def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
    # nobody is allowed to delete
    return False

# suit_classes = 'suit-tab  suit-tab-faults'
empty_value_display = ''
list_filter = ('fault_type',)
search_fields = ('position',)
```

changelist_view html (admin override file)

```html
<!--# machines/templates/admin/machines/machinefault/change_list.html-->

{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% load static %}

<!-- Override extrahead to add Chart.js -->
{% block extrahead %}
{{ block.super }}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

  // Sample data
  const chartData = {{ chart_data | safe }};

  // Parse the dates to JS
  chartData.forEach((d) => {
    d.x = new Date(d.date);
  });

  // Render the chart
  const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Breaks ',
          data: chartData,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,20,20,0.5)',
        },
      ],
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        xAxes: [
               {
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              unit: 'day',
              round: 'day',
              displayFormats: {
                day: 'MMM D',
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        yAxes: [
          {
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Render our chart -->
<div style="width: 80%;">
  <canvas style="margin-bottom: 5px; width: 50%; height: 15%;" id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<button id="reload" style="margin: 1rem 0">Reload chart data</button>
<!-- Render the rest of the ChangeList view -->
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

But my chart is still blank - I have no errors.
Using latest Django, Python3.7
[image]

UPDATE: 2/14/2020
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can't be sure that this is the cause of your issue without seeing the HTML, but the way you are passing data to your chart JS is unsafe - don't do this:

```
const chartData = {{ chart_data | safe }};
```

It's very likely you are ending up with invalid JS as a result of this, because the output is not properly escaped. Instead, use the [json_script](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#json-script) filter to safely render your object, and then read this in JS. Something like this:

```
{{ chart_data|json_script:"chart-data" }}
<script>
    const chartData = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("chart-data").textContent);
    // initialise the chart as you currently do
</script>
```

Note - you need to stop encoding the data as JSON in your view - just pass it the original list which this filter will encode safely for you.

If this doesn't fix it then it's likely that the data structure itself is not what the chart library is expecting - perhaps if you post a sample of what `chartData` looks like we can see whether that looks right.

Comment: Thank you! This is helpful - I'm new to the chart.js part of this. the chart_data is located within the admin.py I posted above the html code. I got the overall formatting from a chart.js tutorial.

Comment: I've added a snapshot of the data. All I want to do is count the number of records per head position. After trying to make the adjustments - i'm not sure I fully understand what you're suggesting that I try. And that's probably just because this is all new.